# Docker How to use environment variables in RUN command, not CMD?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    test_name:
        image: ${PROJECT_NAME}/test_service
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.15

RUN echo $TEST >> test1.txt
CMD echo $TEST >> test2.txt
```

As result:

test1.txt - empty and test2.txt with data.

My problem is that this variables are too much, so can I get environment variables in RUN command from `.env` file without enumeration all of them in ARG?

Comment: I see scheme which steps are exists: https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/ . But I still don't understand how to use it..

Comment: In my Dockerfiles I tend to need fairly few `ARG`s, usually not much more than perhaps a version of the base image and some build metadata.  What leads you to have so many `ARG`s that you're having trouble managing them?

Answer (score 9):

To use variables in a RUN instruction, you need to use [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg). ARG are available at build time while [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) is available when the container runs.

```
FROM alpine:3.15

ARG FOO="you see me on build"
ENV BAR="you see me on run"

RUN echo $FOO >> test1.txt
CMD echo $BAR >> test2.txt
```

```sh
docker build --build-arg FOO="hi" --tag test .
docker run --env BAR="there" test
```

There is one thing that comes close to using env variables, but you still need to provide the --build-arg flag.
You can define env variable with the same name as the build arg and reference it by its name without setting a value. The value will be taken from the env variable in your shell.

```sh
export FOO="bar"
docker build --build-arg FOO --tag test .
```

This also works in compose.

Additionally, when you use compose you can place a .env file next to your compose file. Variables found there will be read and are available in the build:arg key as well as the environment key, But you still have to name them.

```sh
# env file
FOO=bar
BAZ=qux
```

```yaml
services:
  test_name:
      build:
        context: ./
        args:
          FOO:
          BAZ:
```

Comment: Can I get variables from .env file without enumeration all of them in ARG? My problem is that this variables are too much.

Comment: No you cannot use an env file for build args, afaik.

Comment: I believe the statement "To use variables in a RUN instruction, you need to use ARG" is **incorrect** by itself. The documentation for ENV linked states "The ENV instruction sets the environment variable <key> to the value <value>. *This value will be in the environment for all subsequent instructions in the build stage*." This is also discussed in more detail here: https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/.

Comment: @CollinMcCarthy,  you are right. However, the point is more that you can't set env variables at build time. So while you can use env variables in your build, it has very limited use as you can only use the hard coded ones, rendering effectively pointless to use them in the first place. Build args are also seen as env variables during build and those can be set when building.

Comment: Got it thank you